# An array of booleans in javascript

Tags: java, javascript

Not so new to javascript, but the following gives an error in javascript, where as my textbook says it should work.

```
Boolean imgDirection[] = new Boolean[60];
```

What's the problem?

Comment: what does your code look like?

Comment: For someone "not so new to javascript", you seem to be having a problem correctly identifying JavaScript code.  TLDR; that isn't JavaScript.

Comment: The more interesting question is, _What does your textbook look like?_

Comment: To summarize your problem. You are trying to run ___Java___ without the ___Script___.

Answer (score 2):

This code isn't javascript:

```
Boolean imgDirection[] = new Boolean[60];
```

If you wanted to declare a 60 element array in javascript, you could simply use this:

```
var imgDirection = new Array(60);
```

Javascript variable declarations are not typed so there is no such data declaration like `Boolean imgDirection[]`.