# How to make an array of type boolean in JavaScript

Tags: node.js, boolean

I have a variable named `wordRandom` and I would like to use a boolean array as in Java.

```
String[] words = {"yes", "no"};
String wordRandom = words[(int) (Math.random() * words.length )];
boolean[] letterFound = new boolean [wordRandom.length()];
```

For now, I have this in NodeJs

```
var words = ["yes", "no"];
var wordRandom = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
```

I am stuck on the boolean type ?! By searching on StackOverFlow below :

[An array of booleans in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838130/an-array-of-booleans-in-javascript)

I declare my variable as this?

```
var letterFound = new Array[wordRandom.length];
```

This is not good !

My code has an error message on the line -> `var letterFound = new Array[wordRandom.length];`

```
var readline = require("readline-sync");

var words = ["oui", "no"];
var wordRandom = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
var letterFound = new Array[wordRandom.length]; 


for(var i=0; i<wordRandom.length; i++){
    if(letterFound[i]){
        console.log(wordRandom.charAt(i));
    } else {
        console.log("-");
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: use this var letterFound = new Array(wordRandom.length);

Comment: @Milad Raeisi: Thank you Milad